# Error al guardar datos en access : "cannot write indexes of this type due to unsupported collating sort order"

Tags: java, base-de-datos

Hola estoy aprendiendo por mi cuenta a acceder a una base de datos, insertar,eliminar,actualizar, etc, en este caso uso `Access` como base de datos pero tengo un problema al insertar datos en la tabla, me genera el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como puedo solucionarlo?, Aquí mi código

```
   public class Insertar {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ruta = "C:\\Users\\root\\Documents\\BDPrueba.accdb";
        Connection conectar = null;
        Statement mistatement = null;

        try {
            conectar = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + ruta, "", "");
            System.out.println("Conexion Exitosa");
            mistatement = conectar.createStatement();
            String nombres = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite Los Nombres");
            String apellidos = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite los apellidos");
            String id = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite la Identificacion");
            String instruccion = "INSERT INTO Administradores (Nombres,Apellidos,Identificacion) VALUES('" + nombres + "', '" + apellidos + "', '" + id + "')";
            mistatement.executeUpdate(instruccion);
            System.out.println("Insertado con Exito");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: perfecto a mi me funciono pero adicional o lo que se comento en el sitio, "compactar y reparar a la base de datos" esto en el menu herramientas_de_la_base_Datos/compactar y reparar bases de datos.. Luego de esto si dejo trabajar perfectamente... por lo que me doy cuenta esta misma operacion hay q realizarla permanentemente. saludos lusbin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe un problema con el collation definido para el ordenamiento,

> cannot write indexes of this type due to unsupported collating sort
>   order

[la solución es definir un ordenamiento "General"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893630/unsupported-collating-sort-order-error-updating-access-database-from-java).

Abre la base de datos para editar la siguiente propiedad, ve a `File` > `Options` > `General` > en la opción `New database sort order` cambia a `General` o  `General-Legacy`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Nada amigo me sigue generando el mismo error, ya probe con las dos opciones, sin embargo agradezco tu ayuda

Comment: @StevenCamargo ¿editaste la propiedad en BCPrueba.accdb ? ¿probaste con General - Legacy?

Comment: Si probe tanto con General, como con General-Legacy y ninguno me funciono

Comment: @StevenCamargo que collation tiene definida tu BD?

Comment: Amigo retiro lo dicho, resolvi el problema creando una nueva base de datos y aplicando la configuracion que me mencionaste, luego importe las tablas de la base de datos anterior y Listo

Answer (score 0):

Sí, la solución está en modificar en opciones a General-heredado, en mi caso mi access es la 2019 y también hay que tener en cuenta que en las propiedades de los campos, excepto si son autonuméricos, como suelen ser los iD, hay que revisar que en el apartado indexado hay que ponerlos en No, tanto si son de texto o numéricos. Tampoco funciona si intentas guardar un campo de texto corto, deben estar todos en texto largo.